# How can I join meta table with key value pairs as row of parent

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent, key-value

Hi I have this table structure

form_submissions

```
+------+----------------------------------+
| id   | form_id                          |
+------+----------------------------------+
| 3812 | 00184e51e26a41e4a197035b62a1e07a |
| 3815 | 00184e51e26a41e4a197035b62a1e07a |
+------+----------------------------------+
```

form_submission_datas

```
+--------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| id     | form_submission_id | key       | value          |
+--------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
| 534670 |              65952 | ip        | 192.168.255.10 |
| 534669 |              65952 | email     | NULL           |
| 534668 |              65952 | city      | NULL           |
| 534667 |              65952 | phone     | 123-123-1234   |
| 534666 |              65952 | full_name | גל             |
+--------+--------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

My target result is something like this

```
+--------------------+----------------+-------+------+--------------+-----------+
| form_submission_id | ip             | email | city | phone        | full_name |
+--------------------+----------------+-------+------+--------------+-----------+
|              65952 | 192.168.255.10 | NULL  | NULL | 123-123-1234 | gal       |
+--------------------+----------------+-------+------+--------------+-----------+
```

my key value pairs are unpredictable so I can't select ...as 'email' etc.

right now I do this in PHP, but i have forms with 5-7k+ rows and it really non officiant, every page load takes 60-70 seconds and takes more then 2 GB of memory
I would love to have MySQL do this for me.

Comment: I think you want a solution for your solution but not for your problem. This is not how Mysql is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
    form_submission_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'ip' THEN value END) ip,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'email' THEN value END) email,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'city' THEN value END) city,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'phone' THEN value END) phone,
    MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'full_name' THEN value END) full_name
FROM form_submission_datas
GROUP BY form_submission_id
```

This does require you to know in advance the list of keys that may exist in the table; this is because a SQL query must return a *fixed* set of columns. To make this dynamic, you would need to use *dynamic SQL*, which is probably beyond the scope of your question.

NB: as far as concerned you don’t need the submissions table to generate the expected result. If you needed to recover some information from that table as well, you then you would need to add a simple JOIN to the query.

Answer (score 0):

For key value struct you could use  join for each key value pair

```
  select  a.form_submission_id, a.ip
    , b.value as email
    , c.value as city
    , d.value as phone 
    , e.value as full_name
  from  form_submission_datas a 
  inner join  form_submission_datas b  = a.form_submission_id = b.form_submission_id 
    AND b.key = 'email'
  inner join  form_submission_datas c  = a.form_submission_id = c.form_submission_id 
    AND c.key = 'city'
  inner join  form_submission_datas d  = a.form_submission_id = d.form_submission_id 
    AND d.key = 'phone'
  inner join  form_submission_datas e  = a.form_submission_id = e.form_submission_id 
    AND e.key = 'full_name'
  where a.key ='ip' 
  and form_submission_id = 65952
```